# Доступ к объекту в jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Есть скрипт:

```
<?php
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {?>
        <a class="like-icon" href="#"></a>
        <span class="like-count">23</span>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Я хочу получить доступ к `span` при нажатии на `$(".like-icon")` с помощью jQuery.
Вот неправильный код (для демонстрации):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".like-icon").on("click", function () {
        var number = $(this .like-count).html();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше использовать [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) с аргументом, содержащим селектор родственника:

```js
$('.like-icon').click(function () {
  var result = $(this).next('.like-count');  // выбираете искомый элемент... 
  if (result.length) {
    result.css('color', 'red');              // ...и делаете с ним что пожелаете 
  } else {
    console.log('.like-count не найден!');   // [опционально: если элемент не найден - выводим ошибку в консоль, и/или выполняем другие действия]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="like-icon" href="#">Link</a>
<span class="like-count">23</span>
```

Потому что это заметно не повлияет на отзывчивость, и может уберечь от непредсказуемого поведения скрипта, если следующий элемент по каким-то причинам окажется не тем, что ожидается.

Answer (score 1):

Так как `span` - это **следующий** элемент относительно ссылки, для его получения можно использовать метод [`.next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".like-icon").on("click", function () {
        var number = $(this).next().html();
    })
})
```

Comment: неправильный код, следующий елемент не всегда должен быть тем элементом, который нужен.

Comment: @RomanC, судя по генерируемой разметке - всегда.

Comment: @Grundy, _«судя по генерируемой разметке - всегда»_ - поясните, пожалуйста: какой именно участок разметки исключает добавление элементов после `.like-icon`? (добавление средствами JS)

Comment: @yar85, средствами js - никакой. Но тут про это и речь нет. так как в этом случае ни один из ответов не будет верен, так как будет неизвестно как именно искать нужный _like-count_ **относительно** _like-icon_

Comment: @Grundy, конечно же, мы не можем предугадать все варианты. Но мы можем предусмотреть те варианты, которые не учтены основным алгоритмом (и могут привести к ошибке).

Comment: @yar85, нет не можем, так как это в любом случае будет гадание. Например, почему ты думаешь, что если поменяется класс у элемента его не надо будет все еще подсвечивать. как у тебя в примере?

Comment: @Grundy, Вы можете посмотреть мой ответ, он дополнен чтобы показать такую возможность. Обработка ошибок при выборе элемента конечно *не обязательна* (тем более что jQuery глотает исключения), но *возможна*. Просто не понимаю, зачем вводить в заблуждение фразами со смыслом "да все будет ок!.. а если неок - все равно с этим ничего не поделать".

Comment: @yar85, опять же. почему ты думаешь что другой элемент не надо будет обрабатывать? то есть просто поменяется имя класса? Да и лишняя проверка только добавляет код.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77760/discussion-between-yar85-and-grundy).

Answer (score 1):

Выбирайте селектор правильно:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".like-icon").on("click", function () {
        var number = $(".like-icon .like-count").html();
    })
})
```

Comment: этот селектор неправильный, так как выберет все на странице а не только тот который рядом с нажатой ссылкой